# ASP.NET MVC: Best Way To Call Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to decide which is the best way to call a stored procedure.

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I've been reading a lot about Linq to SQL and Entity Framework, as well as the Repository Pattern. To be honest, I'm having a hard time understanding the real differences between L2S and EF... but I want to make sure that what I'm building within my application is right.

For right now, I need to properly call stored procedures to: a) save some user information and get a response and, b) grab some inforation for a catalog of products.

So far, I've created a Linq to SQL .dbml file, selected the sotred procedure from the Server Explorer and dragged that instance into the .dbml. I'm currently calling the Stored Procedure like so:

```
MyLinqModel _db = new MyLinqModel();
_db.MyStoredProcedure(args);
```

I know there's got to be more involved... plus I'm doing this within my controller, which I understand to be not a good practice.

Can someone recognize what my issues are here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

LINQ and EF are probably overkill if all you're trying to do is call a stored proc.

I use Enterprise Library, but ADO.NET will also work fine.

See [this tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson07.aspx).

Briefly (shamelessly copied-and-pasted from the referenced article):

```
    SqlConnection conn = null;
    SqlDataReader rdr  = null;

    // typically obtained from user
    // input, but we take a short cut
    string custId = "FURIB";

    Console.WriteLine("\nCustomer Order History:\n");

        // create and open a connection object
        conn = new SqlConnection("Server=(local);DataBase=Northwind; Integrated Security=SSPI");
        conn.Open();

        // 1.  create a command object identifying
        //     the stored procedure
        SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand(
            "CustOrderHist", conn);

        // 2. set the command object so it knows
        //    to execute a stored procedure
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // 3. add parameter to command, which
        //    will be passed to the stored procedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add(
            new SqlParameter("@CustomerID", custId));

        // execute the command
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // iterate through results, printing each to console
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "Product: {0,-35} Total: {1,2}",
                rdr["ProductName"],
                rdr["Total"]);
        }
    }
```

**Update**

I missed the part where you said that you were doing this in your controller.

No, that's not the right way to do this.

Your controller should really only be involved with orchestrating view construction. Create a separate class library, called "Data Access Layer" or something less generic, and create a class that handles calling your stored procs, creating objects from the results, etc. There are many opinions on how this should be handled, but perhaps the most common is:

```
View
|
Controller
|
Business Logic
|
Data Access Layer
   |--- SQL (Stored procs)
           -Tables
           -Views
           -etc.
   |--- Alternate data sources
           -Web services
           -Text/XML files
           -blah blah blah.
```

[MSDN has a decent tutorial on the topic.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973279.aspx)

Comment: +1 for simple access models ADO.NET while ugly on the API still is king. Shouldn't be surprising since basically every other single data access technology all boils down to ADO.NET.

Comment: Yep. Knew a guy who had a dev argue that enterprise library was faster than ado.net. I LOVE enterprise library, but the DAAB wraps ado.net, so it's pretty silly to claim that it's faster. Know your tools, guys!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

Read:

```
var authors = context.Database.SqlQuery<Author>("usp_GetAuthorByName @AuthorName", 
new SqlParameter("@AuthorName", "author"));
```

Update:

```
var affectedRows = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand
("usp_CreateAuthor @AuthorName = {0}, @Email= {1}", 
"author", "email");
```

From this link:  http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-with-entity-framework-code-first/

And I would go with the framework David Lively mentioned, instead of having the routines in the controller.  Simply pass the results back as `IEnumerable<blah>` from a function in a separate repository class for an edit, pass a boolean back for if the update succeeded for an update.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ to SQL and ADO.NET EF attach read stored procs to the data/object context class that you use to go against its various entities.  For create, update, and delete, you can create a proc that maps the properties of an entity that the model generates, and using the entity mapping window (forget the exact name right now), you can map an entities fields with the proc parameters.  So, say you have a Customers table, EF generates a Customers Entity, and you can map the proc parameters to the properties of the Customer entity when attempting to update/insert/delete.

Now, you can map a CUD proc to a function, but I don't know all the repercussions; I like the way I just mentioned the best.

HTH.

Answer (score -1):

I common pattern is to pass a repository interface into your controller by dependency injection. The choice of what persistence/orm technology you use is really another issue and unrelated to the fact that you are using MVC. Using the repository pattern and coding to abstractions (interfaces) makes your application easy to test by mocking out your repositories.

I think you should also try to use as few stored procedures as possible. This means you can more easily test your logic in isolation (unit tests) without needing to be connected to a database. I would highly recommend looking at NHibernate. The learning curve is fairly steep but you are in full control of your mappings and configuration. There are obviously occasions where you will need stored procs for performance reasons, but using an ORM predominantly is very beneficial.

Comment: Stored procedures should be used where appropriate, not "as little as possible." The first time a DBA came to me to tell me that she fixed a SQL problem that I didn't even know existed was enough to convince me of that. Also, being able to perform compile-time checking on your SQL, as well as abstracting your data layer into components that can be used by multiple applications in multiple languages/platforms, is a benefit not to be taken lightly. I've seen projects crater because the dev decided to switch languages and had to rewrite every freakin' query because they were embedded

Comment: @David, agreed... and this is one of those situations where it's just fine.

Comment: I know this was from 2010, but I took a look at NHibernate once, recently - couldn't even get it to compile!  It is also outdated now as their 1.1 (latest, that I remember) version was not compatible with .NET 3.5, much less 4.0.  Third-party utilities that require that severe ramp-up are also not going to be popular with managers trying to put out a project (and worry when you leave for your next contract).

Comment: Kudos on the repository/dependency injection method for unit testing, though, so I won't knock you, as it is basically what David Lively mentioned, but it does add complexity when you have to add functions in the business layer just to get to the repository, when you don't really need it because you aren't doing full-blown automated unit testing.

Answer (score -5):

I can't imagine that your goal is to be able to call a stored procedure. To me it sounds as if you need to forget stored procedures and use Linq to Sql. I say L2S because EF is far more to learn, and not needed in this case.

Comment: Why do you think his goal isn't to call a stored proc, when he specifically said that it was?