# How to call stored procedure in MVC controller ?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET MVC: Best Way To Call Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259989/asp-net-mvc-best-way-to-call-stored-procedure)

I am developing MCV3 application.

I  want to call store procedure in one of the controller of the applicaiton.

I have already saved store procedure in DB which I am using for applicaiton.

The Query is

```
Create Procedure ConvertLeadToCustomer1
@CompanyID int
as
begin 
update Companies set __Disc__ = 'Customer' where CompanyID = @CompanyID
end
```

Now, I wan to call this procesure into controller...

```
namespace CRMWeb.Controllers
{ 
    public class LeadController : Controller
    {
        private CRMWebContainer db = new CRMWebContainer();

        //
        // GET: /Lead/

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            //return View(db.Companies.ToList());
            return View(db.Companies.OfType<Lead>().ToList());

        }

           public ActionResult Convert(int id)
        {

            // I want to write code here to call stored procedure...


        }
    }
}
```

How to call it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not different in mvc, if using ADO.net, below code call the stored procedure:

```
public ActionResult Convert(int id)
{
    var connection = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING");

    var command = new SqlCommand("ConvertLeadToCustomer1",connection)
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyID", id);

    connection.Open();

    command.ExcuteNonQuery();

    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will this... But In my web.config file I ahev following string....Can I use it as it is ?                             `<add name="CRMWebContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CRMWeb.csdl|res://*/CRMWeb.ssdl|res://*/CRMWeb.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ADSERVER;initial catalog=CRMWEBLIVE11OCT;user id=sa;password=myfair@123;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

Comment: this is not pure connection string. It generated with EntityFrameWork model. If you using ADO.net and want to get the connection string from web.config first change the connectionString attribute to this:data source=ADSERVER;initial catalog=CRMWEBLIVE11OCT;user id=sa;password=myfair@123;

Comment: What change I have to make  if I want to take the ConnectionString. What If I want to use 'CRMWebContainer' Name, connection string name ?

Comment: hey man, google is your friend ;) , use this: ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRMWebContainer"] remember to add using System.Configuration

Comment: I have the fololowing line of code in webconfig `<add name="CRMWebContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CRMWeb.csdl|res://*/CRMWeb.ssdl|res://*/CRMWe‌​b.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ADSERVER;initial catalog=CRMWEBLIVE11OCT;user id=sa;password=myfair@123;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot‌​;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />` and I used the below line of code to get the connection string `string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CRMWebContainer"];` it returning null.