# Web API to call the stored Procedure and return Result

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a Web API that accepts two input parameter called ACC. Created a stored procedure to insert or update the Account table in the SQL server. Account table has just two fields AccountID nvarchar(50) (primaryKey) and Cnt int

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InserUpadte] 
 @Account_TT AS Account_TT READONLY

 AS
 BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 BEGIN TRANSACTION;

 MERGE dbo.[Account] prj
 USING @Account_TT tt
 ON prj.AccountID = tt.AccountID
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET prj.Cnt = prj.Cnt+1
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (AccountID,Cnt)
 VALUES (tt.AccountID, 1);

 COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Now I tried to connect to the SQL server not sure how to how would I call the stored procedure into the ASP.NET Web API application and pass the Account ID in it to create or updadte the table

```
namespace WebService.Controllers
{
public class CreationController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string ACC)
    {
        string strcon =  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection DbConnection = new SqlConnection(strcon);
```

I know we can call the query directly like

```
var strQuery = "SELECT * from ACCOUNT where ACC = :ACC"
```

But dont know how to call the above stored procedure and pass the Account Value. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to pass `Account_TT` table to your store procedure as parameter?

Comment: Thanks @Saadi but I dont know how to call the Stored procedure inside my application

Comment: Look on this link please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259989/asp-net-mvc-best-way-to-call-stored-procedure

Comment: I've created Account table with two fields AccountID nvarchar(50) (primaryKey) and Cnt int. and I try to execute your store procedure query but it's not executing.

Comment: Did you create a TableType  Account_TT ?

Comment: Please share query for TableType Account_TT.

Comment: -- Create the data type
`CREATE TYPE Account_TT AS TABLE
(
AccountID      nvarchar(50)
)
GO`

Comment: Ok. I have posted my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131125/discussion-between-trx-and-saadi).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the complete working example.
Please have a look on it.

```
string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection DbConnection = new SqlConnection(strcon);
DbConnection.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[usp_InserUpadte]", DbConnection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

//create type table
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("AccountID", typeof(string));
table.Rows.Add(ACC);

SqlParameter parameter = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_TT", table);
parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
parameter.TypeName = "Account_TT";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
DbConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Recommendation: Use exception handling for this code.
Thanks!

Comment: Saadi. I tried to execute by passing a value for the ACC in Web API it doesnt through any exception but also does not create any records in the database. I am not sure what I am missing

Answer (score 2):

To call a stored procedure you need to use a `SqlCommand` something like this:

```
string strcon =  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(strcon)) {
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("usp_InserUpadte", connection)) {
      command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      command.Parameters.Add("@Account_TT ", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ACC;
      command.Open();
      var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

      // Handle return data here
    }
  }
```